# How can I crop images for a Bootstrap carousel so they don't appear stretched?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to crop images for a bootstrap carousel but they keep coming out looking stretched or unproportioned.

I want to crop 3 different sizes (small, medium and large) for mobile responsiveness.

The main photo sizes are 940x627, 900x600 and 900x506

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that they have different dimensions. You should use GIMP or photoshop to cut them in some dimension so that they all have the same shape. (for example make them all 900x506). that way they won't get stretched when they are enlarged or made smaller.

Also make sure to use the bootstrap class img-responsive on them.